# Hide/Show a Container in React for login

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have added to my code a login/register container.

`Login.class`

```
const Form = ({ initialState = STATE_LOG_IN }) => {
  const [mode, toggleMode] = useToggle(initialState);

  return (
    <Container pose={mode === STATE_LOG_IN ? "signup" : "login"}>
      <div className="container__form container__form--one">
        <FormLogin mode={mode} />
      </div>
      <div className="container__form container__form--two">
        <FormSignup mode={mode} />
      </div>
      <Overlay toggleMode={toggleMode} mode={mode} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

This Container is caller from my header when the user click on login/register but I do not know how to trigger the show from the login click ?

Header code :

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showLogin: false};
    }

openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }


const menuLoginRegister = <Nav.Link 
            ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} 
            href="#" 
            onClick={this.openLogin}
            bsPrefix="header-menu-item"
            >{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>;


      return (
            ...
            <NavBar>
            ....
            {menuLoginRegister}
            </NavBar>
            <LoginRegisterForm show={this.state.showLogin} 
              onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
            </div>
```

The show from this code show be catched in the `const Form` from the `login` class.

Any idea how to control the visibility of the login class from the header ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason not to opt for a router? Why handle different pages over an eventhandler?

Comment: it will be a modal not a page. I want a pop-uyp

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to show/hide your component by adding a specific class to it based on your state. Something like this:

```
<LoginRegisterForm className={this.state.showLogin ? 'hidden' : ''}/>
```

This will add class `hidden` to your component if `this.state.showLogin` is `true`. In your CSS just define this class as:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```